# setting custom vibration profile on screen touch

Tags: android

i am trying to detect a screen touch on my current application such that when the user touches a part of the screen

my app basically retrieves a text file from the SD card and display's the text in the file onto a textview

is it possible for me to append a customize vibration pattern to the text upon touch

For example, "HELLO" is retrieved from the text file and display via textview

[image]

when i touch on the individual characters, a preset vibration is used

i am using this to achieve the vibrations with all the various patterns set.

```
vibrator.vibrate(pattern101, -1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a SurfaceView/Canvas for this.
Then you have to manage the bounds of each of the character of the text is, and if the finger is within the bounds for that character, play the vibration pattern for that character.

An alternative would be to create a textview/imageview for each character, and add an onTouchListener to each one.

Good luck with your Braille-app. ;-)

Comment: haha it was easy to guess what app it is yea?  thanks for the comments i would try to use the textview method first but that would need a X number of textview depending on the number of character that i am reading right?